# Use Modal as a template view and reference to it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I have modal code (below) wrapped in nav.html and it works as expected (login, logout...works).

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="authModal" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">              
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-signin" role="form">
      <input ng-model="user.email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
      <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
        <input ng-model="checkbox.signup" ng-init="checkbox.signup=false" type="checkbox">
        <label> Sign Up for first-timer </label>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
      <button ng-click="login($event)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I move all modal content to a file named md.html and include it to nav.html via

```
<div class="navbar-header" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-include="'views/modals/md.html'"></div>
</div>
```

It is absolute that I have it included in the ng-controller div.

On testing, I got error of unable to reference to user.password for the Controller. The controller works fine previously and I didn't change anything on it. For this question, I m posting a simplified version of modal and controller code.

```
$scope.login = function($event){ $event.preventDefault();
  // console.log("cond ", cond, ".checkbox.signup ", $scope.checkbox.signup);
  if (!$scope.logged)
  fn.login($scope.user, function(){
    if ($scope.checkbox.signup) fn.signup($scope.user);
  });
};
var fn = {
login: function(user, cb){
    if (Auth.authData) return;

    if (!user.password) {
      fn.alert("please type password");
      return;
    }
    if (fn.valid_email(user.email))
    Auth.ref_ds1.authWithPassword(user, function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        fn.alert(error);
        cb();
      } else {
        authData.email = $scope.user.email;
        console.log("Authenticated successfully on:", authData.email);
        fn.greet("Hello " + authData.email.split("@")[0]);
        $scope.logged = true;
        window.location.href = "/";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

How to reference them correctly?

Comment: error reads - TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could be seeing issues with your `ng-include` creating another scope and you're not able to reference the previously defined user object.

One way I avoid confusion with scopes is using "Controller as" syntax to reference a scope specifically (see http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/).  Here's a tiny example:

```
// in the controller
app.controller('MainController', function() {
    var vm = this;

    this.somevalue = 'something';
})

// markup
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  {{ ctrl.somevalue }}

  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl as secondCtrl">
      {{ ctrl.somevalue }}
      {{ secondCtrl.anothervalue }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Using "Controller as" will really help unwind scope problems you're having, but it would take some re-tooling of your original controller.

Comment: yea, I checked the html elements and saw a nested scope for the modal html code. That local scope is placed in the div wrapping around the modal. I have no way to reference to the parent/root scope. Your answer helps me confirmed of my thinking on the issue but re-tooling does scare me. Apart from the app.js defining modules, configs and states to attach, my MainCtrl in the main.js is about 200 LoCs already and re-structuring seems overwork to me. My main.js includes FirebaseUrl constant, 3 factories (1 for a set of helper funcs, 1 Auth, 1 preload.get() to get data from Firebase),& 1 MainCtrl.

Comment: one thing you could look into is creating a factory that holds the user data, then you could inject that factory into the parent controller and a child controller inside the ng-include so they can share data.

Comment: Ok but I haven't created any child controller for the modal. Different routes come different states and controllers through ui-route defined in the app.js.  In fact IDK if I can inject one controller into another (says injecting 'ModalCtrl' into 'MainCtrl') like I injected factories. My design is bad I know (pls enlight me). Problem with an extra factory is that, my app allows different Auths (Google, Github, email & pw). OAuth from services like Google does not return username & pw to store in that factory.For that factory, we are likely to want generalization but generalization may not work.

Comment: In an attempt, I attached ng-controller="MainCtrl" to md.html file too. It comes like
<div class="modal fade" id="authModal" role="dialog" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
So, I m having <div class="navbar-header" ng-controller="MainCtrl"> in nav.html and within this div.class, I included the md.html code via ng-include. It works on first tests.
Nevertheless, it seems I'm re-declaring ng-controller and both html files now reference to the same controller, is there any issue with this, any issue I will eventually approach?